# ComboBox selection is not visible

Tags: gxt

I am using gxt ComboBox , in the field drop down it is showing values, but when i select a value from the drop down list it is now visible(disappearing). Here i am using setTemplate(), is there any problem with this. Please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?176480-ComboBox-selection-is-not-visible&p=720727#post720727